# Question about the eig() function in GNU Octave

Tags: octave, numpy

In GNU Octave, does the eig() do the balancing of the matrix? I know the eig() in numpy does the balancing of the matrix.

Answer (score 2):

The function `eig` is used to compute the eigenvalues (and eigenvectors) of matrices. In order to balance matrices you can use the function `balance`.
You can check Octave documentation on [basic matrix functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Basic-Matrix-Functions.html).

If your question is related to details of its implementation you can check the [`eig` source code](http://octave.org/doxygen/4.1/d5/db2/eig_8cc_source.html). At a first glance it seems not to be implemented in the code (and no parameter for excluding the preprocessing balance is available, as for instance you can find in Matlab). Hence I would presume it is not performed. I guess you can perform the balance of the matrix yourself as preliminary step (and compare the results).

Comment: Thank you. I have been doing some calculations, in which balancing of matrix may give incorrect result. I compared the calculation results performed by Matlab (with the balancing option being switched off) to that by octave. Unlike numpy, the function eig in octave indeed does not perform balancing, which is a good news to me.